# Android: How to handle long text

Tags: android, button, layout, view, textview

How can I handle in my activity layout long text from which I don´t know how long it is?

I have this text in a textview and when it is too long, it overlays my button.

Comment: if I am not wrong you are trying to fit the view with your text

Comment: Can you post your layout.xml or image containing UI of layout

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you actually want? What sort of design are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about a Textview or Button? If its a Textview ,You can use a marque textview like below.It will scroll automatically so that all the text will be shown

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"

            android:lines="1"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="Your Looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
```

and in your code,

```
    textview.setSelected(true);
    textview.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textview.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    textview.setSingleLine(true);
    textview.setLines(1);
```

If you want an expandable Textview, do something like this.It have a button to expand/collapse textview.

In xml,

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="sdfsdfsdfsfasfdsfgdfgdfsgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdgsdgdsgdsgsdfgdsgdsfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdfgdsfgsdgdsgfsdgfsdgsdfgdsgdsfgdsfgdsfgsdghjghjghjghjghjfg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in code,

```
boolean checkflag = true;// declare it as public

final RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);


    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);



    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(checkflag==true)
            {

            text.setSingleLine(true);
            checkflag=false;
            }

            else
            {
                text.setSingleLine(false);
                checkflag=true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: that works but that isn´t very userfriendly. Isn´t there a way that the user presses a "read all" button and then the text expands and everything under this textview is moved down?